# Rails - Routing error for API namespace when route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes, namespaces, versioning

I have a route to the "spaces" resource in my API:

```
namespace :api, :path => "", :constraints => {:subdomain => "api"} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :spaces
  end
end
```

This corresponds to a controller found at /controllers/api/v1/SpacesController.rb

```
class API::V1::SpacesController < ApplicationController
  ...    
end
```

Whenever I try to access the page at api.[BASE URL]/v1/spaces I get

```
No route matches [GET] "/v1/spaces"
```

Any ideas why? 
NOTE: I have the proper inflector for API to be used instead of Api in the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the route using a subdomain. For an example if you usually open the site in localhost port 3000 then, accessing http://localhost:3000/v1/spaces wouldn't work. In order to make this work on your local environment you should do the following

set a fake subdomain for you localhost. In /etc/hosts set the following,

127.0.0.1 api.test.com

Then, access the site as follows http://api.test.com:3000/v1/spaces

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you, I actually did crate a fake domain for local host: 127.0.0.0 api.test but I didn't have the '.com' which turned out to be the issue.